# FileNotFoundException when using xFire

Tags: java, web-services, xfire

I am trying to expose an existing Java function as a web service using xfire.

I have added this in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <display-name>XFireServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireConfigurableServlet
         </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/XFireServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFireServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and this is my services.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xfire.codehaus.org/config/1.0">

  <service>
    <name>machine</name>
    <namespace>http://xfire.codehaus.org/machine</namespace>
    <serviceClass>com.amazon.lm.util.LMUtils</serviceClass>
  </service>  

</beans>
```

I have placed the `services.xml` file under the `META-INF/xfire` directory and when I try to hit my localhost for the wsdl file, I get `FileNotFoundException` saying that `META-INF/xfire/services.xml file` does not exist.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: XFire is obsolete, and has been replaced by CXF (see http://xfire.codehaus.org/). You'll get better support if you use CXF, very few people use XFire any more.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says the file should be placed "in the classpath" at META-INF/xfire. This means that you want to put it in /yourcontext/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/xfire whereas I'm guessing maybe you put it in /yourcontext/META-INF/xfire ?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>XFire</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireConfigurableServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>../META-INF/xfire/services.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Force the location of the file you need. In this case, I used **".. \"** to go up one level. This is done in ***web.xml***